# Creating a matrix with all combinations within a budget

Tags: r

I am attempting to create a matrix that includes all combinations of numbers within a range such that the row sums to a specific value. I am not sure if there is a function for this or if I would need to create the function manually. I have tried combn function but it does not constrain to the sum and so the matrix gets large very quickly.

example: 3 rows that sum to 5

```
5,0,0
4,1,0
4,0,1
3,2,0
3,0,2
3,1,1
2,3,0
2,0,3
2,2,1
2,1,2
etc..
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These combinatorial objects are called [partitions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set) (see also [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29) and even [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twelvefold_way)), and their computation is implemented by the [**partitions**](http://cran.at.r-project.org/web/packages/partitions/index.html) package.

Depending on what you really want, use one of the following:

```
library(partitions)

## The first argument says you want to enumerate all partitions in which the 
## second argument (5) is broken into three summands, each of which can take a
## maximum value of 5.
blockparts(rep(5,3),5)  ## Equiv: blockparts(c(5,5,5), 5)
#                                              
# [1,] 5 4 3 2 1 0 4 3 2 1 0 3 2 1 0 2 1 0 1 0 0
# [2,] 0 1 2 3 4 5 0 1 2 3 4 0 1 2 3 0 1 2 0 1 0
# [3,] 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 5

restrictedparts(5,3)
#              
# [1,] 5 4 3 3 2
# [2,] 0 1 2 1 2
# [3,] 0 0 0 1 1
```

Comment: +1. I was initially thinking of the partitions package too, but I almost never use the package, so was still reading the docs :-)

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps this does what you want:

```
x <- expand.grid(replicate(3, list(0:5)))
x[rowSums(x) == 5, ]
#     Var1 Var2 Var3
# 6      5    0    0
# 11     4    1    0
# 16     3    2    0
# 21     2    3    0
# 26     1    4    0
# 31     0    5    0
# 41     4    0    1
# 46     3    1    1
# 51     2    2    1
# 56     1    3    1
# 61     0    4    1
# 76     3    0    2
# 81     2    1    2
# 86     1    2    2
# 91     0    3    2
# 111    2    0    3
# 116    1    1    3
# 121    0    2    3
# 146    1    0    4
# 151    0    1    4
# 181    0    0    5
```

`expand.grid` and `combn` are somewhat related, but I find `expand.grid` to be more applicable to these types of problems.

---

There is also the `permutations` function from the "gtools" package:

```
library(gtools)
x <- permutations(6, 3, v = 0:5, set = FALSE, repeats.allowed=TRUE)
x[rowSums(x) == 5, ]
```