# Finding A List of All Combinations of 6 Numbers That Add up to 10

Tags: r, combinations, permutation, integer-partition, iterpc

So I've seen similar versions of this question asked before ([Getting all combinations which sum up to 100 using R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22218640/getting-all-combinations-which-sum-up-to-100-using-r)) but I'm struggling to find a way to figure out what I need to run specifically. I'm trying to create a list in R of all the different combinations of 6 numbers that add up to 10. However, I want to include 0s and repeats of the same # in the row. So it would look something like this:

`10 0 0 0 0 0 
9 1 0 0 0 0
8 2 0 0 0 0`
 
I've tried running the following:

```
C = t(restrictedparts(10,6, include.zero=TRUE))
ComboSet<-data.frame(do.call(rbind, lapply(1:nrow(C),function(i) getall(iterpc(table(C[i,]), order=T)))))
```

However, when I do this it does not seem to include the variations that have 0s in them. I've tried entering the include.zero=TRUE function into different parts of what I'm running but I've had no luck so far. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good question and the answer isn't very obvious.

There are many things to address here. For starters, make sure that you include the 
libraries that you use in your example. I know from experience that you are using `partitions` and `iterpc`. From the `partitions` documentation, we see that there is a function that returns exactly what you are looking for without any additional steps. It is the `compositions` function which generates [Integer Compositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)).

```
myComps <- t(as.matrix(compositions(10, 6)))
head(myComps)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]   10    0    0    0    0    0
[2,]    9    1    0    0    0    0
[3,]    8    2    0    0    0    0
[4,]    7    3    0    0    0    0
[5,]    6    4    0    0    0    0
[6,]    5    5    0    0    0    0

dim(myComps)
[1] 3003    6

all(rowSums(myComps) == 10)
[1] TRUE
```

As for fixing your actual code, I'm not exactly sure why your code is not working as is. I've used `iterpc` in the past and remember explicitly using that same approach. Anywho, the workaround is to explicitly declare the `labels` parameter as the frequency of each element is being used instead of the value itself.

```
## The 1's should be 0's and the 2's should be 10's
ComboSet[1:6, ]
X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6
1  1  1  1  1  1  2
2  1  1  1  1  2  1
3  1  1  1  2  1  1
4  1  1  2  1  1  1
5  1  2  1  1  1  1
6  2  1  1  1  1  1

## OP's original code
ComboSet<-data.frame(do.call(rbind, lapply(1:nrow(C),function(i) getall(iterpc(table(C[i,]), order=T)))))

all(rowSums(ComboSet) == 10)
[1] FALSE

table(rowSums(ComboSet))

7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16 
12  30 150 255 186 690 420 420 180 660

## Here is the fix with labels explicitly declared
ComboSetFix <- data.frame(do.call(rbind, lapply(1:nrow(C), function(i) {
    getall(iterpc(table(C[i,]), labels = as.integer(names(table(C[i,]))), order=T))
})))

all(rowSums(ComboSetFix) == 10)
[1] TRUE

dim(ComboSetFix)
[1] 3003    6
```

You should know that `iterpc` is not being actively maintained and users are encouraged to switch to `arrangements`. It has a different interface, so you can't simply replace the word "iterpc" with "arrangements".

Comment: Thanks Joseph! Sorry, as you can tell I'm new to using this site so I apologize for not properly setting up my question. Using the compositions function was just what I needed and made this so much easier. Thanks again!

Comment: @lordseal92 , no worries... I hope my answer helped you. Like I said, your question was very good, and I hope I didn’t come off harsh as that wasn’t my intention.